# Use of Undeclared Indentifer

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, location

I've been following a tutorial (can't post more than two links, but it's AppCoda's) for getting a user's location for Xcode (with a couple of modifications). Unfortunately, when I tried to build it, I get an error in FirstViewController.h saying

> "Use of undeclared identifier 'longitudeLabel'; did you mean '_longitude Label'?"

Here is my FirstViewController.m, which is the one that is causing me problems:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
//******the two lines above this are causing me problems********
    }
}

@end
```

The two lines near the bottom right above the close paranthesis are the ones causing me the problem (they're also marked with a comment). An important note is that the tutorial was created in Xcode 4, and when I run it with the recommendations applied, the labels for latitude and longitude do not change. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't post links to your files. Update your question with the relevant code (be sure to format it properly). Point out the exact errors and the lines they occur on.

Comment: Assuming you have outlets for the labels, you want `self.longitudeLabel.text =...`. Add `self.` in front of both.

Comment: Thank you, @rmaddy, the error was removed, but the labels were still not updating. Here is an example that I have in .h: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitudeLabel;`. Maybe the button is not triggering getting the location? Is there a way to check? By the way, here is the tutorial:  http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/.

Comment: Use the debugger to see what is happening. Also make sure your outlets are actually connected.

Comment: @rmdaddy, when I started, I control-dragged the labels to the assistant editor in the .h, but does that affect the .m? If not, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Sorry, paging @rmaddy